# How to create a table dynamically in flash using actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am very new to flash and actionscript. I'd like to create a table dyanmically using actionscript code. Please help me.

Thanks in advace.

Comment: what kind of table? data storage? visual element?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a dynamic array, then Action script has native support for dynamic random access containers in the form of their Array() object.

Simply instantiating a new Array object. Just keep in mind that you are responsible for managing the distribution of data in the container yourself. The object will not automatically compress itself if you simply remove an element in the middle of the array.

An example.

```
var numbers:Array = new Array();

numbers.Push("Five");
numbers.Push("Twelve");
numbers.Pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fdc.html

A full documentation on working with arrays and vectors.